# How to select tables from MySQL Database in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a form in PHP with MySQL involved.

The theme of this form, `form.php`, is all about drinks. There are thirteen tables -each table named after type of drink (Belgian beer, wine, soda, rum, ...) that all include only three columns: Id of the drink(PRIVATE KEY AUTO_INCREMENT), the name of the drink and the price (in char). The rest of the columns in other tables are the same, the values are different.

I want to create a dropdown that allows you to select tables from MySQL to add/delete data to the columns within the selected table.

Some names of tables, columns and form elements are named in Dutch.

[Click here to see resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS4JW.png)

These are the things I do know:
  1)Php code to add data to database

```
   <?php

if ( ! empty($_POST))
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','welkom');

    if ($mysqli ->connect_error) 
    {
        die('connect error: '. $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO abdijbieren (naam, prijs) VALUES ('{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['naam'])}','{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['prijs'])}')";
    $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if ($insert)
    {
        echo "Success! Row ID: {$mysqli->insert_id}";
    }

    else
    {
        die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
    }

    $mysqli->close();
}?>
```

2)Form

```
  <form method="post" action="check.php"> <!--check.php is not made yet but when that happens it should be used to automatically update the selected table and auto-return to form.php -->
        <input name="naam" type="text" placeholder="naam drank/snack" required><br>
        <input name="prijs" type="text" placeholder="prijs" required><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
        </form>
```

All I can do with it is to add data to one certain column.
If you know how I can solve this, you are my hero.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk.

Comment: `$sql = mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO abdijbieren (naam, prijs) VALUES (?,?))";
$sql->bind_param('ss',$_POST['naam'],$_POST['prijs']);`

Comment: I think your main problem is a very bad database design. Do a few database design tutorials and then re-design your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select table names like this:

```
SHOW TABLES FROM <your_database>
```

Also to select columns from a table:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM <your_table>
```